# Github actions PM2 start command not starting process

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I'm facing issue with PM2 start. when i push code to master branch all below steps working correctly without any issue. but when i login to my EC2 using SSH and check for `pm2 list` there is no process showing.

I've google a lot but didn't get any working solution.

Below is my workflows yml file

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
 push:
  branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
 build:

runs-on: self-hosted

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [14.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'npm'
- run: pwd
- run: npm ci
- run: npm run build --if-present
- run: pm2 kill
- run: echo 'pm2 process killed successfully'
- run: pm2 start dist/main.js
- run: pm2 list
```